# How to dispose of an object that it created in a task?

Tags: c#

I have a foreach loop that creates multiple tasks like this:

[edit: CreateDisposableAsync returns a Task[IDisposable]]

```
foreach(...)
{
   tasks.Add(CreateDisposableAsync());
}
```

and later I await on all of these tasks, and catch any exceptions:

```
try
{
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
catch (AggregateException)
{
   // handle exceptions
}
```

but the call to CreateDisposableAsync() returns an IDisposable, which I want to be disposed whether or not there was an exception in any of the tasks. How can I do this?

[Edit: It turns out that the CreateDisposableAsync() function was disposing of its created object if itself threw an exception, so there was nothing wrong with the original code.]

Comment: What is the type of `tasks`? Are you sure you need to dispose? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/25/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/

Comment: The easiest would be to ensure that `CreateDisposableAsync` cleans up its own resources so it is responsible for disposing any objects it creates that need disposing.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The return type is Task<IDisposable>

Comment: @MichaelHagar - with the exception of disposing the result do you do (*or want to do*) anything else with the result in the calling code?

Comment: @Igor No I do not.

Comment: @Servy - based on the latest comment I do think the easiest solution would be to have the `CreateDisposableAsync` call clean up its own resources before it returns and return `Task` instead of `Task<IDisposable>`.

Comment: If you're not using the results, why is the method returning anything at all, that is, other than a `Task`?

Comment: @Igor Indeed...

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Other clients use that same function and make use of it, but I don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments

> Q: with the exception of disposing the result do you do (or want to do) anything else with the result in the calling code
>
> A: No I do not

The easiest way to do this is to have the `CreateDisposableAsync` method clean up its own resources before it returns and return `Task` instead of `Task<IDisposable>`. The existing calling code shown in the OP would not have to change.

```
// change the signature
async Task CreateDisposableAsync(){
   // use using blocks for anything that needs to be disposed
   // try/finally is also acceptable
   using(var someDisposableInstance = new SomethingDisposable()){
      // implementation
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only tasks that ran to completion will have returned objects that could be disposed. Just filter the list to the tasks that completed then select the results.

```
try
{
    try
    {
       await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    catch (AggregateException)
    {
       // handle exceptions
    }

    //do other stuff with the returned task objects.
}
finally
{    
    foreach(var item in tasks.Where(x=>x.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion).Select(x=>x.Result))
    {
        //We use a try block so if Dispose throws it does not break the loop.
        try
        {
            item.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Log any exception on dispose.
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you do not plan on doing any other work after the `WaitAll`

```
try
{
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
catch (AggregateException)
{
   // handle exceptions
}
finally
{    
    foreach(var item in tasks.Where(x=>x.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion).Select(x=>x.Result))
    {
        //We use a try block so if Dispose throws it does not break the loop.
        try
        {
            item.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Log any exception on dispose.
        }
    }
}
```

Tasks that threw errors don't return objects, there is no way to dispose of them outside of `CreateDisposableAsync()` and it would be that function's responsibility to dispose of them if there was any kind of error.

```
public async Task<MyDisposeableClass> CreateDisposableAsync()
{
    MyDisposeableClass myDisposeableClass = null;
    try
    {
        myDisposeableClass = new MyDisposeableClass();

        //...

        return myDisposeableClass;
    }
    catch
    {
        //dispose of the class if the instance was created.
        if(myDisposeableClass != null)
            myDisposeableClass.Dispose();

        //let the execption bubble up.
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not know if the OP wanted additional work done after the `catch (AggregateException)` but before the object was disposed. If there is nothing to be done in `//do other stuff with the returned task objects.` then as Servy mentioned the two try blocks can be merged and a `try/catch/finally` can be used.

Comment: @Servy No, because the `AggregateException` will kick you out of the try block, so if you wanted to do something with the results that did complete successfully it would need to after the `catch (AggregateException)` block. EDIT: However, [after reading the OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750215/how-to-dispose-of-an-object-that-it-created-in-a-task/39750333?noredirect=1#comment66797413_39750215) I see he is not doing any extra work. So it could be merged. I will update my answer.

Comment: Quite right, didn't consider that (although based on recent comments on the question, we both missed what's actually going on here).  Also, I'll note that, by convention `Dispose` should never throw an exception, but of course, in practice, it might.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this here because it seems like an alternative solution:

```
    private static async Task CallCreateDisposableAsync()
    {
         using (await CreateDisposableAsync()) { }
    }
```

and then

```
foreach(...)
{
   tasks.Add(CallCreateDisposableAsync);
}
```

that way the using statement can dispose the created IDisposable.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but if `CreateDisposableAsync` throws an exception though it will still not be disposed as it never formally enters the `using` block. This means you are still left with the same problem and Scott's answer would be the best alternative if you cannot change your call signature.

Comment: @Igor If it throws an exception then there is never an exposed `IDisposable` object that could be disposed of, so there is nothing to be done (from the point of view of an external caller anyway; internally any method returning a disposable resource should have a try/catch and dispose of the resource if it could potentially throw an exception any time after the creation of the resource but before it is returned).

Comment: @Servy - wouldn't that depend on where the Exception is thrown in `CreateDisposableAsync` assuming that this method creates Disposable instance members? I made that possible assumption based on the fact that the OP mentions the IDIsposable result should always be disposed of even in the event of an Exception. So yes, assuming the `CreateDisposableAsync` cleans up if there is an exception there is no problem.

Comment: @Igor If it creates disposable instance members then it's not the return value of the method that needs to be disposed, but the instance calling the method, which is a pretty radically different situation, and is handled by ensuring that the instance calling the method is disposable and is properly disposed of.